# TypeScript compiler is not emitting imported modules

Tags: typescript, configuration

I have the project ([on GitHub](https://github.com/idenisovs/ts-projects-example)), which uses the [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) functionality of TypeScript compiler, so it have the root `tsconfig.json` file and the `tsconfig.json` file of subfolder named `shared`.

`Shared` subfolder have 2 files:

- `User.ts`
- `Point.ts`

The main `index.ts` file imports the `User` module, like

```js
import User from './shared/User';
```

Transpiled files is placed under the `target` folder. The issue I met is that as result of `tsc` the `target` folder has `Point` .d.ts and .js files (**not imported** by `index.ts`) and **doesn't** contains the `User` files (imported by `index.ts`).

The output of `tsc -b --listEmittedFiles`:

```
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/index.js
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/index.d.ts
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/shared/Point.js
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/shared/Point.d.ts
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/shared/User.js
TSFILE: /home/user/Projects/test/target/shared/User.d.ts
```

If I remove the `import` expression from `index.ts`, the target folder will have both `User` and `Point` scripts, as expected.

My question is: Is it bug of `tsc` or I'm doing something wrong?

Tested on both `3.3` and `3.4` versions of `tsc`, with same result.

The root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./target",
    "rootDir": "./source",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./source/shared"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` of `shared` folder:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This behavior is driving me crazy - I can't figure out why it occurs/how to reason about it.

Comment: Yes, finally I got the solution by myself! I'll publish it here in couple of hours, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got the solution by myself!

`tscconfig.json` files of **subprojects** should point output to the `target/` directory of main project!

So, let say, you have general project with `source/` directory defined as `rootDir` and `target/` directory as `outDir`.

In the `source` directory you have two subprojects: `core` and `geometry` (as it shown [here](https://github.com/idenisovs/ts-projects-example/tree/master/source)).

So, both of them should have `outDir` set to the main `target/` directory, like that: `../../target/core`, `../../target/geometry`.

**Or**, use [configuration inheritance with "extends" property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends). In this case the config files of subprojects may be rewritten like that ([example](https://github.com/idenisovs/ts-projects-example/blob/master/source/geometry/tsconfig.json)):

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true
  }
}
```